# Cordova 11 Cross Domain Issue

Tags: jquery, cordova, fetch

I have searched in google and also SO for days to resolve my issue. But nothing can resolve my issue.
I want to build just simple mobile apps with **Cordova latest version (Cordova version 11.0.0)**.
The problem is about croos domain to fetch data from external domain.

At the **index.html** file I have put the code below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://app.example.com 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:*;">
```

And for **jquery request at index.html**, I have put below:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
    });
</script>

<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ambilCoba()
    {
        var loginString ="view=all";
        
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType:"json",
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                url: 'https://app.example.com/test.php',
                data: loginString,
                success: function(json){
                    $('#kotbah').html(json['output'][3]);
                }
            });
          }

</script>
```

As I read at SO, the place for jquerymobile must be correct. I have tried to place it with many position, but still no luck.

At the **config.xml** file I have put below:

```
<access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

And at the external domain that I want to fetch the data (**test.php**) I have put this code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');   
header('Content-Length: 0');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$p=array(1,2,3,4);
return json_encode($p);
?>
```

At the index.html of Cordova, **it should print the result is 4**. It works in local browser. But when I tried to run at Android Emulator, it show nothing. Trying to build the APK file and installed it at the mobile phone, no result too.

I also trid to use XMLHttpRequest as being suggested in SO. The code is below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                            var container = document.getElementById('kotbah');
                            container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                alert(this.status); 
                                alert(this.statusText);
                alert(this.responseText);
                            }
                    }  
        
                    xhr.open('GET', 'https://app.example.com/APP/test.php', true);                  
                    xhr.send(null);
```

I set alert for status to see what exactly happen in Android. And at the Android Emulator the **alert for status is 404**, meaning of page not found. But the URL is truly exist.

I have tried it for days, but still no luck. 2 years ago, I use cordova but different version, and no issue is shown with the config above.
I also read that I need to use **whitelisting-plugin**. I tried to do so, but at github, it said that whitelisting-plugin is no longer need at Cordova version 6 and later.

What am I missing with all of that code to fetch PHP data from external domain? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 choices. Either set the same domain as your API using the host scheme.

```
 <preference name="scheme" value="app"/>
 <preference name="hostname" value="localhost"/>
```

Or bypass the security by using for Android

```
 <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

for iOS

```
 <plugin name="@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr">
 <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
```

Comment: If I want to fetch PHP data from example.com, then I have to set as follows:
<preference name="scheme" value="app"/>
     <preference name="hostname" value="example.com"/>
Is that correct?
I read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712710/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview-custom-scheme-not-working-on-android, there are several valus for **scheme**. What is the difference? And should it be set to "app"?

Comment: You can set it to https <preference name="Scheme" value="https" /> for your CORS backend. It all depends on how you set your backend

Comment: I have tried with value https or app in <preference name="Scheme">, but no luck. I have tried to use <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />, and no luck too. My remote PHP file is just has the code: ```<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$p=array(1,2,3,4);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($p);
?>```. I just want to fetch just that data. But the Android Emulator show nothing. What do I need to check further?

Comment: Hostname set to app.example.com ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the hostname value is app.example.com. Tryting with value https://app.example.com. And also with value: example.com. But none works. I even tried to the different vps, but the reuslt is same. Isnt there any better method to fetch PHP and Mysql Data from external domain?

Comment: The plugin was archived, and also this solution does not work anymore. The issue is related to the server API, so we have to enable CORS for them.